# Setting bindable value to label in Actionscript (no curly brackets in mxml)

Tags: apache-flex, binding, mobile

I've got a model class with custom change events, which is working fine if I make a reference to that class in my mxml using;

```
[Bindable] private var firstClass:FirstClass;
```

The objects gets filled by a server side script, so don't worry, firstClass isn't null.

Anyhow, accessing firstClasses properties in mxml works perfectly fine using curly brackets. The binding works just as expected.
However, is there any way to access firstClasses properties and set them to say a label with pure Actionscript.

```
lblTest.text = firstClass.property;
```

The code above doesn't work. I suppose because it sets a fixed value to the label.
I'm aware of using `BindingUtils.bindProperty` to explicitly set the source and destination for the binding. However, this turned out to cause huge performance issues in my (mobile) application. 
So is there a simpler, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I doubt it. Binding using curly braces uses the same code as `BindingUtils.bindProperty` behind-the-scenes, so in mobile apps where memory is an issue, binding is not really a great thought

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks mate. Is there a better way than using binding? I'd like to avoid writing all the events myself.

Comment: Thats what bindingUtils was written for, but when you create more and more bindings, the memory used will increase naturally

Comment: Right, so I should rather stick to manually binding properties using the BindingUtils, than using automatic binding using curly brackets? I'm a little confused right now.

Comment: Jeez no. Use curly brackets or bindingutils its the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The BindingUtils uses `propertyChanged` events to detects when an object's property changes. You won't be able to bind something  without listening to events, and the most painless way to do it is using BindingUtils.

Comment: Fair enough, I will stick to BindingUtils then. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It may be painless, but because it is a static Class, it can also cause memory leaks, whereas if you do it manually the objects can only hold each other in memory.